# How to stop Handler (). postDelayed using onBackPressed

Tags: java, handler

The handler keeps running even after pressing back from the LoginActivity. When I press back from LoginActivity to MainActivity continues to run and takes me back to the LoginActivity. How can I stop this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.